# php array_search associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the key from an array by searching for its value. In the following code, what I don't understand is why [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) can't find the key when the `$url` file extension is `"xls"` but it can when it is `"php"`. I've noticed a similar issue of not being able to "find" `"xls"` using [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
$url='http://mysite.com/hello.xls';
$url='http://mysite.com/hello.php';

$extension_arr=pathinfo($url);
$extension=strtolower($extension_arr['extension']);

$arr=array(
    'excel_file'=>'xls', 
    'excel_file'=>'xlsx',
    'php_file' =>'php'  
  );

$array_search_key=array_search($extension, $arr);
if($array_search_key !== false){
  echo $array_search_key;
}
else echo 'crap';
```

Comment: You need to flip the keys and values of the array, it's not possible to associate more than one value with a given key. You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to perform the function you require when the keys and values are swapped.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks. It looks like this can also be solved by giving each key its own unique value, so something like `'excel_file xls'` and `'excel_file xlsx'`. Would you mind making an answer flipping the keys and values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your search works, but the array you're searching is flawed. Element 1 (xlsx) overwrites element 0, because the keys are the same.

```
$arr=array(
  'excel_file'=>'xls', 
  'excel_file'=>'xlsx',  // This overwrites the line above.
  'php_file' =>'php'  
);
```

Flip the elements around and then you can just check if the key exists:

```
$arr=array(
  'xls'=>'excel_file', 
  'xlsx'=>'excel_file',  
  'php'=>'php_file'  
);

if (isset($arr[$extension])) {
   // do stuff
   echo $arr[$extension];
}
```

Comment: You could go for an array of `excel_files` too, that would probably be more valid.

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug the $extension if its display the wanted value (xls), try to swap the key and the val, and try to find by new key:

```
$aux = array();

foreach( $arr as $key => $val )
{
    $aux[ $val ] = $key;
}
```

so you try to find the current value:

```
if ( isset( @$aux[ $extension ] ) ) echo "I found the current extension";
else "extension not found!";
```

Comment: Isset is not necessary, you can just if ( @$aux[ $extension ] )

Comment: You should use isset and remove the shut-up operator @. Good habit.